# cakephp can't connect to database when on server

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have my Cake app and it's is working on my PC on Apache but it connects to the remote database.
And everything is fine.

But when I copied my app on server, there is an error when I try to execute any controller:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'xx.xx.xx.xx:33306' (2) requires a database connection

Error: Confirm you have created the file : app/Config/database.php.
```

And I tested the connection in simple php script (on server) and I connect and get data from this database without problem. So why Cake can't connect to it?? What might be problem?

```
public $external = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx:33306',
        'login' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'database' => 'xxx',
    );
```

The file 'database.php' exists in app/config and has permissions rwxr-xr-x
I am not sure about mod_rewrite... how I can check it?

Comment: Well... maybe a dumb question on my part, but did you double check and make sure you have `app/Config/database.php` on the server?

Comment: It's not that Cake can't connect to the server - it's that it's not able to find your database.php file - maybe the file isn't there?  mod_rewrite isn't enabled?  file/folder permissions?

Comment: I think mod_rewrite is ok because when I type mydomain.xx/controller/param it correctly goes to the right place but it flashes this sql error

Comment: are you sure that  syntax   host:port is allowed? i'd try with "host" => "xxxxxxxx" , 'port'=>''    then, are you sure that port is 33306 ?(usually is 3306, maybe one "3" is a typo)

Comment: You were right - I had to change to port => 'xxxx' - I dunno why it worked on my PC :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx:33306',
```

is not allowed.  You should use the optional port option as specified in the [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html).

```
public $external = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'port' => '33306',
        'login' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'database' => 'xxx',
    );
```